# Exercise in Beauville, about the blowup of $P^2$ at seven points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, surfaces, blowup

I am trying to solve: (this is an exercise in Beauville's book, Complex Algebraic Surfaces, page 52.)

Consider $7$ points of $P^2$ in general position. Let $P_7$ denote the blowup of $P^2$ at these points and $H$ the strict transform of a cubic containing them. Show that $|H|$ defines a two-to-one map $P_7 \to P^2$ branched along a smooth quartic.

I showed that $|H|$ is base-point-free, so there is a well-defined map $P_7\to P^2$, but I can't show the rest. How can we show that this map is branched along a quartic?

Comment: Let $L$ denote the pullback of the class of a general line in $P^2$ to $P_7$. The degree of a finite map over $\mathbb C$ is the cardinality of a general fiber. Since a general point is the intersection of two general lines, and $H$ is by definition the class of the pullback of $\mathcal O_{P^2}(1)$, we can compute this as the intersection number $H^2 = (3L - E_1 \cdots - E_7)^2 = 9L^2 + E_1^2 + \cdots + E_7^2 = 9 - 1 - \cdots - 1 = 2$ where all cross terms $E_i . E_j$ and $L.E_i$ vanish because $L$ is general, and because blowing up general points produces disjoint exceptional divisors.

Comment: It is a classical fact that projection from a general point on a smooth cubic surface $S$ produces a morphism from the blowup $\tilde{S}\to \mathbb P^2$ branching along a smooth quartic. $S$ is blowup of 6 general point, so $\tilde{S}$ is exactly $P_7$ and the morphism is exactly given by the linear system of cubics vanishing on the 7 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment because I figured out what errors I was making before: let $L$ denote the pullback of the class of a general line in $P^2$ to $P_7$. The degree of a finite map over $\mathbb C$ is the cardinality of a general fiber. Since a general point is the intersection of two general lines, and H is by definition the class of the pullback of $\mathcal O_{P^2}(1)$, we can compute this as the intersection number
$$
H^2 = (3L - E_1 - \cdots -E_7)^2 = 9L^2 + E_1^2 + \cdots + E_1^2 = 9-1-\cdots -1=2,
$$

where $L.E_i$ and all cross terms $E_i.E_j$ vanish because $L$ is general, and because blowing up general points produces disjoint exceptional divisors.

As for the branching, this is essentially a topological question. The topological Euler characteristic $\chi$ of $P^2$ is $3$, and blowing up a point (since it replaces a point with a $2$-sphere) increases $\chi$ by $1$, so $\chi(P_7) = 10$. Now when we have a branched double cover $X\to Y$, we can think of $X$ as being constructed by cutting away the branch locus $C$ from $Y$ to get an affine variety $U$, taking two copies of $U$, and gluing back together along a single copy of the branch locus, so $\chi(Y) = 2\chi(U) + \chi(C)$. Filling in what we know we get
$$
10 = 2(3 - (2-2g(C))) + (2-2g(C)) = 2(1 + 2g(C)) + 2 - 2g = 4 + 2g(C)
$$

hence $g(C) = 3$. Now assuming that $C \subset P^2$ is smooth, it must be a quartic by the degree-genus formula.

To see that $C$ is smooth requires a local calculation that I will leave to you. You want to show that the surface defined by $w^2 = F(x,y,z)$ in $P^2 \times A^1$ is smooth if and only if the plane curve $F=0$ is smooth. Since we know $P_7$ is smooth, we conclude that $C$ is smooth.

Comment: Thanks. Does the first result imply that the map $P_7\to P^2$ is onto?

Comment: The map is onto basically by construction. if $I_7$ is the ideal sheaf of the seven points, then the dual of $V=H^0(P^2, \mathcal O(3)\otimes I_7)$ is a $3$-dimensional vector space whose projectivization is the target $P^2$. The reason we have to blow up is because every section vanishes at the seven points, so the map is undefined there. But surjectivity of the rational map or the resolution is somehow just the statement that every $s \in V \setminus 0$ vanishes somewhere on the domain $P^2$ or its blowup.